# Php and Javascript fails W3 Validator XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Tags: php, xhtml

I am using the following php and javascript

```
if ($name == "" || $name == $required)
{
echo"<p><span>Name</span></p><input size=\"60\" id=\"name\" name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"$name\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == '$required') {this.value = '';}\" onblur=\"if (this.value == '') this.value=this.defaultValue;\"$name\""
;}
```

which results in this:

```
<p><span>Name</span></p><input size="60" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Required" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value=this.defaultValue;"Required" />
```

However the w3c validator says:

> Line 60, Column 220: Line 60, Column 220: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter
>       … '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value=this.defaultValue;"Required" />
>
> Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value".

On that same line I also get the additional errors:

> Error Line 60, Column 221: end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>       … '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value=this.defaultValue;"Required" />
>
> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
>
> Info Line 60, Column 25: start tag was here
>
> Name

Anyone have any ideas for making this valid?
Thanks
Mark

Comment: Can you not see that `this.value=this.defaultValue;"Required" />` is an issue?

Comment: Well, first of all... WHY are you using an outdated, derelict version of xHTML? Are you using XML at all? If not, lets get into this century, shall we? Second, why are you having inline javascript? That will NOT play well with XHTML. Use proper handling of javascript events, without using onblur, onclick and other abominations.

Comment: As you can see in the result its adding an extra `"` at the end, though why not use single quotes? also as the condition is `required` you don't really need the variable `$required`, also im not sure how the name would ever have the value Required?

Comment: What **exactly** is your markup supposed to look like?

Comment: Also, the second error message is simply caused by the odd number of quotes in the output, causing the /> to be inside quotes as far as the validator can see. Simple as that.

Comment: Fist thanks for the replies . The site is what it is i am not interested in updating the completely. I do not see the extra quote at the end I see a single double quote around the word "Required". If those quotes are removed the javascript does  not work. Mr Lister thanks for pointing that out. I am concerned about making it compliant and fnding the errors while having it qwork. The PHP is easy for me the java is a mystery

Comment: Mr Lister, I think you are confusing double single quotes for a single double quote

Comment: I can not see the issues I do not know how it "should be" If I knew why would I ask
 If I start replacing double quotes for single quotes then the javascript  does not work anymore.

Comment: @user178167 No, I am not confusing single and double quotes, nor is the W3C validator. There is an odd number of double quotes in the output, which is a syntax error. The validator is pointing this out. And the problem is we don't know how to correct this, because we don't know what the output was meant to look like.

Comment: All I can say at this point is that replacing all double quotes by single ones will not solve the issue: it will result in an odd number of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

*Always* use curly brackets `{}` in JavaScript and PHP; disregard slacker code that omits them; strict code is the best code.

Secondly PHP uses single 'quotes' and double quotes differently.

```
<?php
$a = 'user';
echo 'Hello $a';//Hello $a
echo "Hello $a";//Hello user
?>
```

Secondly concatenation (periods in PHP, plus signs in JavaScript) is what you seem to be having trouble with in regards to the value. Avoid double quotes (negligible performance gain if any though being sharp about context of programming is more important in the long term).

```
<?php
$a = 'user';
echo 'Hello '.$a.', how are you?';//Hello user, how are you?
?>
```

I've chopped up the `input` element in to several lines in PHP simply for easier reading. I never avoid horizontally long lines of code in my live (or what many refer to as "production") code. It is an excellent way to note that you've "finalized" that code. The log viewing program Hoo WinTail correctly implements horizontal scrolling by allowing you to use the `Ctrl` key when using the scroll-wheel, something I wish they'd implement everywhere, especially Notepad++ (highly recommended advanced code editor).

Also keep your HTML attributes alphabetical. It will greatly improve your ability to quickly fix earlier bad coding habits if your code is predictable using programs such as Advanced Find and Replace.

Bringing it altogether:

```
<?php
if ($name == "" || $name == $required)
{
 echo '<p><span>Name</span></p>';
 echo '<input id="name" name="name" ';
 echo 'onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '.$required.';}" ';
 echo 'onfocus="if (this.value == '.$required.') {this.value = '';}" ';
 echo 'type="text" value="'.$name.'" />';
}
?>
```

Lastly you're using XHTML. A critical clarification is needed here. The highest level of programming is to use XHTML5.

There are parsers that take code:

- HTML parser
- XML parser

And there are the standards for the code:

- HTML4
- HTML5
- XHTML 1.x

You'll want to use HTML5 with the XML parser (XHTML5):

```
<?php
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
{
 header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8');
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
}
else
{
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
}
?>
```

The XML parser is *much stricter* and (Gecko rendering engine, in Firefox but use Waterfox now instead) so it will output errors instead of letting them happen. Being aware of errors allows you to fix them and greatly increase compatibility. If you're not aware, you won't fix those errors and thus you won't be more capable and it'll be more difficult to distinguish yourself from others. Quality is critical in a world that has mostly abandoned quality. See my website in my profile for more good code (look at the source code). Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I get:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '') {this.value = '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/clients/client6/web8/web/contact.inc.php on line 44

where line 44 is:
 
    echo 'onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '.$required.';}" ';

this is exactly as posted here

Comment: I was missing a couple periods for the `$result` variable on the line with the `onfocus` attribute. Just add a period before and after: `.$result.`. If you're unsure in general when you encounter an error just comment things out for a single line with `//` or multiple lines with `/* line breaks here */`.